# Javascript Regular Expression Works on OSx NOT on Windows

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been developing a javascript application on OSx with Safari as the main browser, I am trying to migrate this application to a windows system with WAMP as my server.

The code has not changed, however it will no longer work correctly and when carrying out the find within an array using the regular expression. I receive the return value as false which should not be the case. If anyone can take a brief look at this code and give me some opinions I would be very grateful.

```
Array.prototype.find = function(searchStr) {
        var returnArray = false;
        for (index=0; index<this.length; index++) {
            if (typeof(searchStr) == 'function') {
                if (searchStr.test(this[index])) {
                    if (!returnArray) { returnArray = [] }
                    returnArray.push(index);
                }
            } else {
                if (this[index]===searchStr) {
                    if (!returnArray) { returnArray = [] }
                    returnArray.push(index);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnArray;
    }
    var newIndexTargetID = window.indexTargetID;
    var searchStr =RegExp(newIndexTargetID,'i');
    var regexp1=mytool_array.find(searchStr);       
    alert ("2" + mytool_array[regexp1])
    var previousProperty = mytool_array[regexp1];
    mytool_array[regexp1] = "[[" + timeLimitID + "," + '"' + l[j].sourceId +
    '"' + "," +  timeLimitProperty + "]]" + "(" + previousProperty + ")";
    finalResult = mytool_array.join(' ');
```

Comment: Please indent and format your code properly (use spaces). I don't want to have to scroll to the right in order to read your code.

Comment: Fun part is, that was all spaces.  Fortunately the `{}` button is dumb enough to re-outdent code.  :)

Comment: I have tried to clean up the code , hope this helps, Thanks again

Comment: One problem right off the bat: You are inadvertently creating a global variable: `index` in the first `for` loop. Need to make it: `var index=0`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of a regular expression object is not `function` but `object`. At least in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

I suggest that you swap the code in the `if` statement and check if the type is `string`, as the type of the `RegExp` object seems to differ between browsers.

Comment: Fantastic ! Thnakyou very much !!